# Subsetting dataframe with values of two columns are equal to each other at same time, to check for zero at all other columns

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset, multiple-conditions

I am a beginner to R programming. I am currently using a dataframe with 865921 rows with 8 columns. I wanted to subset the dataset in which two columns that has same values and at the same instance, I also wanted to check the zero values at all other columns. But I couldn't overcome this step. It will be very helpful if any one could help or suggest any steps to go forward. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "check the zero values at all other columns" ?

Comment: 1st step is `new_df <- subset(old_df,colA == colB)`

Comment: new_df <- df[(df$col1==df$col2)&(df$col3!=0)&(df$col4!=0)&(df$col5!=0)&(df$col6!=0)&(df$col7!=0)&(df$col8!=0),] ?

Comment: to check the occurrences of zero in all the other columns @ Moody_Mudskipper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you need:

```
# create a sample dataset
auto <- mtcars

# subset by columns being equal
auto_2 <- auto[auto$gear == auto$carb, ]

# find where the zeros are
zeros <- apply(auto_2, 1, function(x) all(x != 0))

# subset to remove rows with zero
auto_3 <- auto_2[zeros, ]
```